# Riddle containing other languages than english

Tags: discussion, question-quality, asking-questions

Is it allowed to create riddles containing partly languages which are not english? If yes, which languages are allowed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to post a puzzle written in a specific language, then sorry you can't (according to [this policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/)). But if you want to post a puzzle which needs the knowledge of any specific language, please feel free.

[language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) tag should only be used in case when the answerer needs to know about a foreign language while answering, not while reading the puzzle.

Have a look at [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange) too.

Comment: The puzzle would be partly in another language, otherwise it would not make sense in the context. If that is not possible, I will design it completely in english (but that would destroy the context).

Comment: @arc_lupus I think it is purely opinion based. Some people might be ok with that puzzle while others might get frustrated for not having enough knowledge about that language. So by asking me, you are only taking the opinion of single person. And who knows if others agree or disagree with my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for finding that the language issue has been settled at the SE level, manshu! @arc_lupus, I would very much enjoy seeing your puzzle, and think many others would as well, if introduced in English, then completely described in its native language, and finally answered similarly, with an English introduction. (I'd feel enriched even if it had no English at all and I used computerized translation to understand any of it.) Many puzzles here rely on technical or cultural details that are equivalent to being in an another language.

Comment: @humn: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/30889/4043

Comment: Nicely done, @arc_lupus, an excellent example for future posts

Answer (score 3):

There is the tag [japanese](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese) for puzzles that use Japanese characters or the Japanese language. You may want to check out the corresponding puzzles,
and compare the puzzle-type to your puzzle.

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese

Comment: [This](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29460/an-italian-rebus) puzzle uses italian words.

Comment: Good examples, Gamow and @manshu, ones considerately introduced in English at that. Super! (Even if they included no English I wouldn't mind, thanks to the infinitesimal effort required to ignore inscrutable posts.)